# Plotting time series of NDJFM (ND previous year and JFM of succeeding year) daily data using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample data:

```
dput(dat2)
structure(list(YY = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L), MM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
DD = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L), RR = c(1, 35.5, 20.3, 2.5, 32, 66.8, -888, 0, 1.8, 
0, 5.3, 0, 0, 0, 11.7, 40.4, 45.7, 15.3, 21.6, 10.5, 26.2, 
54.1, 1.5, 26.9, 39.4, 21.6, 1.3, 95.6, 10.2, 0, 5.1, 0, 
4.1, 2.9, -888, 0.5, 2.1, 15.7, 14.2, 28.7, 134.2, 26.3, 
-888, 0, 0, 2.3, 0, 2.8, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 
0, 0, 3.3, 13.6, 32.9, 47.7, 1.8, 78.8, 27.1, 0, 0, 45.5, 
2, 1.4, -888, 0.5, 0, 0, 19.8, 11.4, 8.7, 0, 0, -888, 4.8, 
0, 2.5, 10.5, 24.7, 0.8, 10.4, 6.9, 13, 0, 0, 0, 3.1, 2.8, 
23.9, 2.8, 0, 1.8, 7.4, 29.8, 0.5, 0, 0, 27, 16.5, -888, 
6.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.6, 0.6, 1.3, -888, 0, 9.7, 2, 15.3, 6.4, 
11.1, 0.5, 16.8, 1.5, 0, 2.3, 1.3, 0, 3.6, 95.5, 3.4, 1.3, 
35.3, 0, 1.3, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 36.3, 0, 6.1, 1.8, -888, 4.8, 
0, -888, -888, 0, 0, 0, 0, -888, 2.3, 5.9, 52.1, 2.5, 3.8, 
15.7, 0, 7.9, 8.9, 0, 0, 5.6, -888, 26.2, 9.1, 22.6, 1.8, 
17.5, 68.1, -888, 2.3, 3.1, 9.7, 105.9, 30.7, 3.8, 0, 31.2, 
11.7, -888, 0, 18.8, 6.3, 3.6, -888, 0, -888, 0, 43.3, 0.5, 
1.3, 49.3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4.3, 6.4, 5.4, 0.3, 64.8, -888, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -888, 38.1, -888, 8.4, 0, 0, 3.3, -888, 4.4, 1.6, 
0, 0, 7.4, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 1.5, 3.3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 6.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36.6, 45.2, 13.9, 
5.1, 0, 0, -888, 1.8, 0, 0, 1.3, 0, -888, 0.5, 0, -888, -888, 
2.3, -888, 0, 0, 25.7, -888, 3.6, 0.3, -888, -888, 0, -888, 
-888, 19.1, 22.1, 24.2, 0.5, 5.1, -888, 0, 0, 0, -888, -888, 
2.3, 0, 0, 1.5, 11.5, 21.3, 28.2, 67.8, 55.7, 25.3, 2.3, 
27.5, -888, 0, 14.2, 10.4, 12.7, 14.7, 9.7, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -888, 14.5, 0.5, 10.6, 0.5, 2, 1.5, 7.4, 14.3, 15.2, 0, 
37.1, 18.3, 0.5, 3.3, 4.9, 68.6, 1.5, 0, 4.1, 20.1, 25.3, 
23.9, 6.3, 26.2, 50.8, 15, 1.1, 44.2, 1.5, -888, 0, 0, 0, 
14.5, 24.4, 0, 39.1, 151.7, 26.4, 1, 3.6, 2.5, 0, 1.3, 4.1, 
7.1, 1.8, 7.6, 84.7, 1.5, -888, 9.1, 31.5, 24.6, 18.5, 0, 
37.1, 111.3, 4.3, 21.1, 3.1, -888, 0, -888, 15.8, 30.7, 6.4, 
68.6, 97.5, 64.3, 47.3, -888, 2.3, 8.7, 53.9, 6.9, 20.9, 
94, 7.4, 0, 1.3, 0, 10.9, 0, 81.8, 10.2, 2.5, 1, 3.1, 12.3, 
41.9, 85.9, 74.4, 13.8, 79.9, 117.7, 16.5, 31.2, 1.3, 1.3, 
4.6, 7.1, -888, -888, 0, 2, 4.8, 2, 3.8, 94.2, 1.8, 3.6, 
4.6, -888, 0, 0, 1.3, 1.8, 0.3, -888, 2, 8.5, -888, 1, -888, 
17.5, 6.1, 1.5, 5.1, 0, -888, 0, 0, 0, 37.3, 17.5, -888, 
2, 2.8, 26.2, 0.9, 0, 71.9, 3.6, 15.3, 70, 12.8, 34, 14.7, 
1.3, 4.3, -888, 5.4, 0, 1.3, 6.9, 0, 0, 2.5, 7.1, -888, 3.6, 
-888, 0, 1.8, -888, -888, 43, 37.6, 45.3, 11.2, 4.9, -888, 
21.3, 1.5, -888, 0, 5.3, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33.3, 
0, 0, 90.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.6, 0, 0, 0, 8.9, 0, -888, 
6.6, 0, 24.6, 62.2, 81.6, 21.6, 28.5, 0.3, 12.7, 10, 0, 0.8, 
1.3, 4.1, 62.5, 10.2, 0, -888, 0, 1.5, 20.8, 0.5, 0.3, 6.9, 
32, -888, 1, -888, 0, 0, 13.2, 6, 5.1, 0.3, -888, 6.4, -888, 
0, 0, 0, 31.2, 14, 0.5, 38.6, 18.3, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 7.4, 66.1, 
0, 0, 14.7, 12.5, 68.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.1, 0, 30.3, 0, 30, 
9.6, 43, 37.4, 0, 8.2, 0, 1.8, 7.4, 0, 0, 1.6, -888, 0.8, 
-888, 18.5, 79.7, 0.3, 5.4, -888, 11.9, 2, 1, 6.1, 1.3, 12.5, 
8, 26.6, -888, 1.5, -888, 10.9, -888, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 8.1, 
8.6, 21.8, 0, 14, 0, 0, 18.8, 1.3, 0, 5.3, 2.5, 0, 0, 0.8, 
2.3, 0, 7.1, -888, 73.1, 2.5, 0, 7.6, 2.5, 1.3, 8.1, 22.1, 
18.5, 0, 5.1, 11.5, 2.1, 1, 62, 10.4, 108.5, 1.3, 11.5, 6.4, 
0.8, 48.2, 15, 22.6, 0, 27.4, 1.3, 29.2, 0, -888, 0, 0, 0, 
-888, 0, 0, 0, 6.6, 15.7, 22.9, 8.3, 0, 6.4, 0, 5.4, 0.3, 
11.5, 0, 8.4, 5.6, 57.2, 0.8, 6.1, 0, 2.3, 34.8, 25.7, 82.6, 
40.9, 6.1, 8.4, 0, 0.3, -888, 15.5, 0.3, 0, 13.4, 1.5, 36.3, 
2.6, 2.3, 15.8, 37.9, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, -888, 0, 0, -888, 102.3, 
165.7, 152, 40.7, 33.2, 114.3, 29.4, 88.9, 38.6, 2.5, 10.4, 
22.6, 6.3, 20.2, 3.6, 30.8, 0.8, 0.5, 34.3, 315.9, 246.3, 
131.1, 11.8, 4.9, 2.1, 0.6, -888, -888, 0.5, 0.3, 122.2, 
85.9, 40.2, 9.4, 15.4, 27.7, 2.3, 41.1, 248.9, 0, 20.1, 2.8, 
21.1, 50, 102.8, 23.9, 58.4, 39.7, 3.1, 1.3, 3.5, 3, 1.3, 
0, 3.8, -888, 0, -888, 1.3, 4.3, 3.1, 41.2, 1.3, 0.5, -888, 
3.8, 0.8, 3.3, 0.8, 1.8, 0, 9.2, 34.3, 18.1, 7.6, -888, 7.1, 
44.2, 10.5, 13, 9.6, 24.4, 1.3, 0, 1, 8.9, -888, 3.6, 22.6, 
10.4, 0.3, -888, 39.5, 60.4, 13.2, 1.3, 35.4, 16, 1.3, 9.4, 
1.6, 2.5, 0, 4.9, 6.1, 47.2, 4.1, 4.1, 27.7, 32, 27.2, 2.6, 
1, 0, 0, 0, -888, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.3, 5.1, 1, 36.6, 0, 15.1, 
26.7, 20.1, 25.4, 8.6, 85.3, 13.4, 8.9, 1, 25.4, 3.3, 0, 
3.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 10.9, 0.5, 31.4, 10.9, 2.5, 0, 
20.1, 1, 0, 0, 19.4, 0, 3.1, 0, 0, 1, -888, 7.9, 0, 0.8, 
35.8, -888, -888, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 33.5, 3, 91.4, 0, 0, 11, 4, 
4.3, 0.3, 11.7, 55.6, -888, 0, 3.3, 3.8, -888, -888, 12.4, 
-888, 0, 0.8, 8.2, 20.3, 12.8, -888, 19.3, -888, 3.1, -888, 
0.8, 4.3, 0, -888, -888, 0, 0, 0.8, -888, 0.6, 22.4, 16.2, 
1, 0, 23.6, 50.8, 3.8, -888, 4.1, -888, -888, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -888, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -888, 0, 0, -888, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.3, -888, 0, -888, 17.3, -888, 0, 4.4, 13.7, 
0.8, -888, 30.2, 23.4, 23.1, 6.2, 6.4, 60.1, 11.4, 0.8, 15, 
0, 3.6, 0, 3.3, 0, 0.3, 34.1, 19, -888, 12.8, 16.5, 0, 4.1, 
6.4, 0, -888, 0, 47.6, -888, 1.5, 0, 0, -888, 45.3, 1.3, 
0, 34.1, 2.8, 7.2, 3.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3, 3.3, 2.5, 
3.5, 20.3, 0.5, 1, 19.1, 30.6, 56.2, 40.9, 4.8, 31.8, 29, 
17.8, 6.3, 11.2, -888, 0, 14.7, 40.1, 20.8, 1.5, 11.1, 53.8, 
8.4, 0, 8.4, 0, 6.1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4.1, 11.4, 47.8, 54.3, 4.8, 
115.3, 59.7, 131.6, 50.7, 0, 0, 29.6, 40.2, 4.1, 0, 17.8, 
7.6, 0.8, 0.8, 9.4, 1.8, 1, -888, 0, 0, 3.8, 27.9, 1.3, 1.6, 
0, 4.8, 0.8, 2, -888, 0.5, 7.4)), row.names = c(NA, 1096L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is daily rainfall from January to December.

(a) I would like to plot November to March (NDJFM) time series, where the ND is for the current year and the JFM for the succeeding year.

For example, one NDJFM is composed of ND of 1979 and JFM of 1980.

(b) I will be applying this for a data set with data from 1979 to 2020 (40 winters).
I would like to plot the average time series of these 40 winters using ggplot in R.
Y-axis is rainfall (mm/day) and x-axis is months (Nov 1 to March 31).

So far, I manually do this in excel. I would like to know how I can do this in R.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the downvotes. It's expected that askers demonstrate at least an honest attempt at whatever it is they are having trouble with. I would suggest you upvote and accept G. Grothendieck solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert dat2 to a zoo object RR calculate the mean, mu, and NA out the values that are not in winter or are less than zero.  Plot that using autoplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

toDate <- function(y, m, d) as.Date(paste(y, m, d, sep = "-"))
RR <- read.zoo(dat2, index = 1:3, FUN = toDate)

is.winter <- dat2$MM %in% c(11:12, 1:3)
ok <- is.winter & RR >= 0
mu <- mean(RR[ok])
RR[!ok] <- NA

autoplot(cbind(RR, mu), facet = NULL)
```

[image: screenshot]